# Rails: Approach for users of the app to send email, not the app itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, actionmailer

The feature i'm trying to accomplish is:

**Jane signs up to my Rails app as a new user, creates a fan page for other users to join. 
(GOAL:) Jane can now send emails to group members about events, updates, etc. and the 'from' is her email.**

Are there any gems or another approach to let users enter their email credentials + SMTP settings so they can send emails from within the app, and not an in-app messaging system?

I've only found documentation on ActionMailer and Devise Mailer to send welcome emails, reset-password emails, etc., but nothing generated by users.

Comment: The OmniAuth gem could allow your users to sign-in with their GMail credentials and may allow you to send email with their gmail accounts. But I don't think it is a good thing: I would not like that a website can send emails via my email account as if I sent it myself. Instead, you could send email with your domain's email and put the author in bcc.

Comment: +1, I'd never give a permission to a site to send emails through my account, it's better to explain the situation to the recipient that your user sent him a message and use the [reply-to](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.2) field if your message is supposed to be discussed between them.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like asking for trouble, can't you just change the "from" address when sending email?

```
mail(to: 'somebody@some_domain.com', from: 'jane@gmail.com')
```

Comment: You can't for obvious security reasons : I could send an email to your friend and pretend that the author is you ...

Comment: Higher chance of being flagged as spam

Comment: @MrYoshiji you actually can, never believe emails, at least before looking at raw message with headers, that's security mailing lists are digitally signed for.

Comment: It does not work with gmail at least, I can't change the `from` address when sending emails through our gmail company accounts with our Rails apps. It uses the address given to authenticate to gmail.

Comment: Also check out this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058743/can-i-send-email-from-different-addresses-using-same-actionmailer